# Return the index of the max number in a 2d array of ints in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am trying to return the max value of an array of arrays in ruby

for 1d array this works

```
arr = [99, 3, 14, 11, 1, 12]
position = arr.each_index.max
```

how can I achieve the same thing for multi-dimensional array in ruby

```
arr = [[99, 3, 14], [11, 1, 12], [1.....]
```

I have tried using flatten and then finding the index of the max and trying to work out column and row but didn't get correct results and felt wrong, is there a clean way to achieve this with ruby? thanks.

Comment: Do you want two indexes for 2d array?

Comment: `arr.each_index.max` returns the max index, not the index of max element.

Comment: which is the same as `arr.length - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get the max value:

```
m = arr.flatten.max
#=> 99
```

Then it sounds like you either want the index of the array containing m:

```
arr.index{|x| x.include? m}
#=> 0
```

or that index plus m's index in that array

```
[i = arr.index{|x| x.include? m}, arr[i].index(m)]
#=> [0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you @pguardario this worked, sorry to others if question wasnt detailed enough, I will mark up when I am able

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
arr.map(&:max).max
```

To find an index try:

```
1.9.3p125 :018 > arr = [[99, 3, 14], [11, 1, 12], [1,10]]
 => [[99, 3, 14], [11, 1, 12], [1, 10]] 
1.9.3p125 :019 > arr.map{|sub| sub.each_with_index.max}.each_with_index.max_by{|sub_max| sub_max[0]}
 => [[99, 0], 0]
```

Comment: This returns the max value, not the index of the max value (classic case of title of question being different from the text).

Comment: @steenslag But then, the first line of the question is `I am trying to return the max value of an array of arrays in ruby`.